# Optimising C code

Tags: c, optimization

Here is my C code..

```
void Read(int t,char* string1)
{
    int j,i,p,row,count=0;
    for(i=0;i<t;++i,string1=strchr(string1,')')+2)
    {
        sscanf(string1,"(%d,%d)",&p,&row);
        CallFunction(p,row);
    }
}
```

Here is how i have to call this function:

```
Read(2,"(3,5),(7,8)")
```

Is this a good way to deal with such kind of input parameters? Is it time consuming?

Is there any other good way (optimised way) of reading the same input parameters?

Comment: why do you think you have to optimise it?

Comment: just wanted 2 know if this is the only way of reading this kind of input or any other better way

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. By the way, you can probably make this code more readable, without the loss of performance, for example, by moving `string1=strchr(string1,')')+2` out of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the %n format-specifier for sscanf(), which allows you to omit the strchr() function. The speed improvement is probably marginal.

BTW: dont' call a function "Read", not even if you can assume a case-sensitive compiler and linker.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CallFunction(a,b) fprintf(stderr, "p=%d row=%d\n", a, b)

void do_read(int cnt,char *input)
{
    int i,err,p,row,res;

    for(i=0; i<cnt ; i++,input += res )
    {
        err = sscanf(input,"(%d,%d)%n",&p,&row, &res);
        if (err < 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: input='%s', err=%d\n"
                        , __FILE__ , __LINE__,  input, err );
                break;
                }
        CallFunction(p,row);
        if (input[res] == ',') res++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
do_read(2,"(3,5),(7,8)"); /* this should succeed */
do_read(2,"(3,5)#(7,8)"); /* this must fail ... */

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is reasonably fast. But how fast it needs to be depends on your constrainsts which are unknown to me.

I hope that your input data is already checked because `string1=strchr(string1,')')+2` (and what follows) is not safe.

Reading your code makes me think that, if you *really* need bare to the metal speed, you should ditch the function calls and do the job manually (parsing the string yourself).

But given the 'API' you have published, the question of the speed may be defeated ABOVE and BELOW this code snippet.

Reaching the optimal code chain then depends on... all the chain: the whole will not run faster than the slowest function in the chain.

Sorry not to be more specific but this is really a more global question than the information you provide lets me address it (I don't have the whole picture).